# Kik Card - Synchronous XMLHttpRequest in the Kik.js file

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, xmlhttprequest, kik

I'm all ready to build a Kik-powered mobile web app!

Okay so step one, throw this Kik.js script into the bottom of your HTML page...

```
<!-- simply include this script in your webpage -->
<script src="http://cdn.kik.com/kik/2.3.6/kik.js"></script>
```

Great stuff. Now let's fire up the console and do some testing:

[image]

What the hell? Why aren't they using an async request here? Am I missing something? In the network tab, it appears that the requests are indeed going through, but the warning is annoying and (as it clearly states) will contribute to a bad user experience.

How can I get around this/if someone from Kik is reading this, what is the reasoning here?

Answer (score 2):

The Kik Dev Chrome Extension injects code to make requests, simulating in-app behaviour. Synchronous network means that the webapp can inject code that will simulate Kik before your application code runs, ensuring that the webapp behaves like within Kik as much as possible

Comment: Yep, removed the extension and bam no more warning! Now I'm going to maybe re-install it now that I know more about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it is only the [kik-dev-tools Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kik-developer-tools/occbnccdhakfaomkhhdkmmknjbghmllm) that is making that sync call and not the client-side kik.js library they provide.